# SVG con height auto no se muestra en firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

Con una imagen en formato svg estoy teniendo problemas al aplicarle este CSS:

```
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 128px;
    max-height: 128px;
```

La imagen me sale en todos los navegadores excepto en Firefox.

El `height:auto` lo tengo para que se me vaya escalando en función me redimensionen la pantalla pero si lo tengo así es cuando no me lo muestra en FF.

¿Como puedo hacer para que me lo muestre pero me lo escale bien en caso de redimensionar la pantalla?

Answer (score 1):

Podés asignar el height en base al tamaño de pantalla y ponerle un class a tu svg... (El concepto sería así como hace bootstrap para manipular el responsive de algunos recursos que posee)

```
@media (min-width: [tamaño_minimo_de_pantalla]px) {
  .class_de_tu_svg {
    height: ___px;
  }
}
```